# Unable to continue perform perl script after ssh to another unix domain

Tags: perl, unix, ssh

Encounter a question here whereby need help from you guys

I am writing a perl script that will be executed in a UNIX machine. In that script, I will perform an operation of 'ssh' to port over to other Unix domain (from A ssh to B). The problem now is after I port over to domain B, I still need to perform some operations from the perl script (for example: echo Hello World!). The issue here is after port over to the new unix domain, the following script after 'ssh' could not be performed as the script still over the "old domain". Is that anyway to solve this issue or any better way to achieve the same objective?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Expect` module](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod) to open an SSH connection and execute commands over it via Perl.

If you need help beyond that, you'll have to explain more specifically what you are trying to do.  It is possible that you have the wrong design for solving your task.

Comment: What I mean is that the 'ssh' commands is within the perl script. For instance:   system " ssh xxxxxxx"; system "echo Hello World"; the echo part could not be performed as after ssh, the script can be continued to execute.

Comment: means you're trying to execute echo "hello world" on the remote server?

Comment: yes, exactly! What I figure is that after the system ssh to the remote server, it could not continue to perform the following commands, as the script is not in the remote server. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks for your help

Comment: @user2218886, the module I mentioned solves exactly the problem you are having.  You can't use `system` to open an SSH connection, because you need *two-way communication* over SSH in order to execute commands.  The `Expect` module does this.  Click on the link and see the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
ssh <servername> "echo 'hello world'";
```

Also check ssh with -t option.For checking if this echo command is running on the server or the localhost, try some other command like ls".

**Note:** : ssh connection will get closed when script will terminate.